# Choosing random sprite from sprite group

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am buiding a game where I have 5 aliens stored in a sprite group, then at random it is decided that 1 of the aliens must 'drop' a bomb object. My problem is that I don't know how to get the index of the sprite group member that drops a bomb. Idealy if the sprites where stored in a list I would implement it like this:

```
import random

num_elements = len(alien_list)
choice = random.randrange(0,num_elements)
element = int(choice)
chosen_sprite = alien_list[element]
```

how would this be done when the alien objects are stored in a sprite group as illustrated here:

```
alien_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.sprite.Group.sprites()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.sprites) returns a list of all the *Sprites* in the *Group*:

```py
alien_list = alien_group.sprites()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a pygame group to a list simply by doing `list(group)`:

```
alien_list = list(alien_group)
```

You can easily choose a random sprite from it by using `random.choice`:

```
from random import choice

chosen_sprite = choice(list(alien_group))
```